# Delete numbers from a file

Tags: python, regex, scripting, sed, awk

I have a file of the form

```
00040 void FormExample::setLanguage(const std::string lang)
00041 {
00042   bool haveLang = false;
00043
```

I want to remove the numbers from the file so that it can compile. 
I tried using 
    sed -e 's/^(\d)*//g' test.cpp but was not successful. Please tell me what was I doing wrong.

It can be any other standard unix tool besides sed. Shell script, python script, awk etc will also be considered.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
sed -e 's/^[0-9]*//' test.cpp
```

[`sed`'s regex flavor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html#bre) is a bit different than Perl's. You don't have this "shorthand" character classes ( e.g. `\d` or `\w`)  and grouping is done by `\( \)`. The parenthesis in your expression match literally.

Comment: You don't need the `g` - there's only one "start of line" per line

Comment: thanks. Accepted your answer for 2 reasons:  1) First to answer and 2) Explained what I was doing wrong.  For others - all answers work. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/^[[:digit:]]*//g'
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

In case when each line started with 5 digits and space:

```
res = [line[6:] for line in open(fileName, 'r')]

f = open(fileName, 'w')
for line in res:
    f.write(line+'\n')
f.close()
```